# Разделить bmp изображение на 3 разных цветовых составляющих php

Tags: php

Ну то есть грубо говоря есть картинка, и мы ее должны разбить на 3 отдельных файла со своим цветом (r,g,b)

```
             (B, 0, 0)
(B, G, R) -> (0, G, 0)
             (0, 0, R)
```

выглядеть на схеме это примерно вот так, как мне дописать имеющийся уже код.

```
 $fp = fopen("example1.bmp","r");
              $data = fread($fp,54);
              $biWidth = (((((ord($data[21]) << 8) + ord($data[20])) << 8) + ord($data[19])) << 8) + ord($data[18]);
              echo "Ширина: ".$biWidth."<br/>"; //1200
              $biHeight = (((((ord($data[25]) << 8) + ord($data[24])) << 8) + ord($data[23])) << 8) + ord($data[22]);
              echo "Высота: ".$biHeight."<br/>"; //800
              $dobavka = (4 - (($biWidth * 3) % 4)) % 4;
              echo "Добавка: ".$dobavka."<br/>"; //0
              $fp1 = fopen("examplenew1.bmp","w");
              fwrite($fp1,$data);
              //1B,1G,1R,2B,2G,2R,3B,3G,3R,4B,4G,4R,5B,5G,5R
              for($i=0;$i<$biHeight;$i++) // чтение строки картинки
                for($i=0;$i<$biHeight;$i++) //чтение точки картинки
```

Comment: открывайте сразу три файла на запись и пишите построчно, оставляя только нужные данные

Comment: как мне реализовать "оставляя только нужные данные"?